# retry to send failed messages sent via C# in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, email

we send email messages using Office 365 SMTP AUTH client submission, however some message are failed to sent and error is returned "failed to send message" is there via code that i can try and resend those messages until the emails are sent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would not do it in a way "until it succeeds" as it is very risky, but could be achieved easily with code:

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        SendEmail();
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Now consider - what if email provider/server is down? You app would hang until the server starts to work correctly again.

You would need to setup some threshold and retry policy - for example - after first fail, wait 5 seconds and retry, after second fail wait 30 seconds and retry, and so on. After 5th fail terminate process or do some other action.

Comment: Surely won't do it with a `while(true)` loop without any control. I'd maybe do with a limited number of maximum retry attempts. Also, I'd introduce some delay between the tries, so there is time on the receiving side to recover from some error potentially.

Comment: @CsabaBenko Of course, I included in the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Microsoft has a limit of 30 emails per minute, i suppose the emails are dropped when i cross the limit of 30 email per minute. a retry after 5 minutes and a second retry after 10 minutes is fine with me.

Comment: @WilliamDias as far as I know, the 30 p/min is more of a throttle. Meaning you can send 300 emails within a few seconds, but it will end up taking around 5 or so minutes before the last one is actually delivered. I speak under correction, but I have observed this behavior in my .Net Core application using smtp.office365.com